# NSDateFormatter Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

I am running instruments and it keeps saying that there is a 100% leak on the NSString *date = [df2 stringFromDate:dt]; line.  I look at examples from apple and they are basically doing the same thing.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or if the instruments are wrong.

```
 +(NSString *) shortDateToLongDateString:(NSString *) dtString
 {
     NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

     NSDate *dt = [df dateFromString:dtString];
     [df release];

     NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [df2 setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];
     NSString *date = [df2 stringFromDate:dt];
     [df2 release];

     return date;
 }
```

I am calling the method as follows:

```
 for (NSString * dt in uniqueDates)
 {
    NSString *longDate = [NSString stringWithString:[NSDateHelper shortDateToLongDateString:dt]];

    //Do something with the result...
 }
```

Comment: There is no leak on those lines how code. Have you run the Clang Static Analizer?

Comment: Running on device right?

Comment: Doesn't matter where. Just select analyse and see what it gives you.

Comment: Yes I have run the static analyzer.  The analyzer does not show any issues.  The code also runs fine.  However in the leaks section of the profile instruments it says 100%.  There are also a lot of other places that it claims has memory leaks, but my app never crashes.  Have you seen this and are these really leaks?  Can a leak from another location make it appear that it is coming from here?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the function is being executed in a secondary thread that doesn't have an active NSAutoreleasePool.  If you look in the console log you'll probably find "just leaking" warnings printed (though without anything in the way of info on where the leak is).

Implement the method more or less like this:

```
+(NSString *) shortDateToLongDateString:(NSString *) dtString
 {
     NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

     NSDate *dt = [df dateFromString:dtString];
     [df release];

     NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [df2 setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];
     NSString *date = [df2 stringFromDate:dt];
     [df2 release];

     [date retain];
     [pool drain];
     return [date autorelease];
 }
```